# Mapping a list of tuples using a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Given the following list of tuples:

```
y = [(1, 2), (3, 5)]
```

and the following dictionary:

```
d = {1: 'a', 2: 'c', 3: 'n', 4: 'y', 5: 'u'}
```

is there a simple way of mapping y onto `[('a', 'c'), ('n', 'u')]`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this:

```
>>> y = [(1, 2), (3, 5)]
>>> d = {1: 'a', 2: 'c', 3: 'n', 4: 'y', 5: 'u'}
>>>
>>> [(d[k], d[v]) for k,v in y]
[('a', 'c'), ('n', 'u')]
>>>
```

Comment: @g.d.d.c Simplified the access to the tupels' elements. `tupel[x]` is almost always an inconvenient way to access the tupel's elements

Comment: @phihag - Thank you! I always forget to unpack inner tuples, but that does clean it up a bit.  :)

Comment: a nitty comment, but I really don't like `k` and `v` as variable names here, because it strongly suggests they are keys and values of a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

If the elements of y are not guaranteed to be 2-tuples, you can use:

```
>>> d = {1: 'a', 2: 'c', 3: 'n', 4: 'y', 5: 'u'}
>>> y = [(1, 2), (3, 5, 4)]
>>> [tuple(d[i] for i in tup) for tup in y]
[('a', 'c'), ('n', 'u', 'y')]
```